# Nested case statement within if then statement

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, case

I'm having trouble running a simple script, it works fine without the new case statement. What I would like is for my script to be able to "Catch" special characters that are "Accidentally" entered by a user as an argument on the command line and to output an error message. What I have so far is as follows:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then echo "Please enter a filename."
else
  if [ -f $1 ]
  then
    starting_data=$1
    sed '/^id/ d' $starting_data > raw1
    sed 's/-//' raw1 > raw2
    sed 's/-//' raw2 > raw3
    sed 's/,//' raw3 > raw4
    sed 's/,/:/' raw4 > raw5
    cut -f1 -d\  raw5 > col3
    cut -f2 -d\  raw5 > col2
    cut -f3 -d\  raw5 > col1
    paste -d\  col1 col2 col3 > final
    name="Joe"
    echo $name
    date
    cat final
  else
     if case $1 in
          [!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:'",<>?/]) echo "One or more characters not 
supported."
                                         echo "Please try again."
                                         ;;
        esac
     else
    echo "$1 cannot be found."
     fi
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, no need to use these many `sed` or `awk`s if you could let us know sample input and sample output we could try to help you on same then too.

Comment: What sort of "trouble" are you having? Please elaborate.

Comment: Here's an example of me running my script, hw9.sh and providing a simple argument (a file that does not exist)                                                                         $ ./hw9.sh xxx
./hw9.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
./hw9.sh: line 23: `          [!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:'",<>?/]) echo "One or more characters not supported."'

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `sed -e '/^id/ d' -e 's/-//' -e 's/-//' -e 's/,//' -e 's/,/:/' "$starting_data" | cut -f1-3 -d\  > final` and further optimizations to get rid of `cut` too are probably possible.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that the character class expression, `[!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:'",<>?/]`, contains a number of character that need to be escaped (at least in bash, other shells may differ), and `-` is treated as indicating a character range unless it's at the beginning or end of the expression. This seemed to work for me: `[-!@#$%^\&*\(\)_=+{}\|\;:\'\",\<\>?/\\]`, but I woudn't recommend it. I'd instead recommend using a negated expression of allowed characters, like `[^[:alnum:].]` or `[^a-zA-Z0-9.]` (i.e. any character *except* a letter, number, or period).

Second problem: the pattern only matches a single unsupported character, not a string *containing* an unsupported character. So you actually want `*[^[:alnum:].]*`

Third problem: you're trying to use `case` directly in an `if` statement (i.e. `if case...`), which is technically legal, but probably doesn't mean what you want. Just leave the `if` part off, and use a `*` pattern as an `else` case:

```
case $1 in
  *[^[:alnum:].]* )
    echo "One or more characters not supported."
    echo "Please try again."
    ;;
  * )
    echo "$1 cannot be found."
    ;;
 esac
```

Some other potential problems: You have a number of unquoted variable references (e.g. `if [ -f $1 ]`) that can cause trouble if there are any funny characters in the variable; these should almost always be double-quoted (e.g. `if [ -f "$1" ]`). You're also checking for unsupported characters *after* looking for the file; if the file exists with unsupported characters in its name, should the script go ahead and run, or reject it and complain? Note that almost anything is legal in unix filenames.

Finally, as RavinderSingh13 said in a comment, there's no need to use such a long string of `sed` commands. Without knowing more about the file format and what you're trying to do with it, it's hard to make good suggestions, but I'm sure there's a better way.